# Merge dataframes with same name within a list when dataframe lengths differ

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list that contains several dataframes. My goal is to merge the dataframes that share the same name together. However, although two dataframes may share the same name, they do not always share the same number of rows. I followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020773/how-to-merge-dataframe-within-a-list-by-the-same-name-in-r) until I encountered my issue below. I have included a reprex below that is an extension of this issue.

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- data.frame(id = "111", y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 2, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(id = "111" , y1 = c(2, 1), y2 = c(4, 4)) # missing a row
d3 <- data.frame(id = "222", y1 = c(2, 2, 3), y2 = c(2, 2, 6))
d4 <- data.frame(id = "222" , y1 = c(3, 2), y2 = c(2, 4)) # missing a row
d5 <- data.frame(id = "333", y1 = c(5, 5, 3), y2 = c(0, 2, 6))
d6 <- data.frame(id = "333" , y1 = c(3, 6, 7), y2 = c(1, 9, 4))

lst <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)
rm(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6)
names(lst) <- c("111", "111", "222", "222", "333", "333")
lstdf <- map(split(lst, names(lst)), bind_cols)
#> Error in `.f()`:
#> ! Can't recycle `..1` (size 3) to match `..2` (size 2).
```

Using the `do.call(cbind, x)` option causes a similar issue. My goal is to "cut off" the extra row and have the minimum number of rows for any ID number (if the ID number contains differing number of rows between its two dataframes). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use a function that pads `NA` when the lengths are not same i.e. `cbind.na` from `qpcR` does it

```
library(purrr)
 map(split(lst, names(lst)),  ~ reduce(.x, qpcR:::cbind.na))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
lst <- lapply(split(lst, names(lst)) , \(x) do.call(rbind , x))

lapply(lst , \(x) {row.names(x) <- NULL ; x})
```

- output

```
$`111`
   id y1 y2
1 111  1  4
2 111  2  2
3 111  3  6
4 111  2  4
5 111  1  4

$`222`
   id y1 y2
1 222  2  2
2 222  2  2
3 222  3  6
4 222  3  2
5 222  2  4

$`333`
   id y1 y2
1 333  5  0
2 333  5  2
3 333  3  6
4 333  3  1
5 333  6  9
6 333  7  4
```